# Store the results of grep -q and use them later iff they return true in a conditional statement containing other code

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm writing a style-checking script that:

- looks for some abuse of style using grep
- prints a message and the offending lines IF they are found
- otherwise, prints nothing

I'm currently using

```
if (grep -Erq 'break;|continue' *) then 
    echo && echo "found breaks and/or continues:"
    grep -Ern 'break;|continue' *
    else echo "no breaks or continues found."
fi
```

Is there a way to store the result of the first grep (the one in the if conditional with the -q flag) to use later (between the echo statements), or do I have to do the search twice if I want to print out the intermediate echo messages? I understand there are simple workarounds to this particular problem; this is a smaller example of something I want to do at-scale.

Comment: `grep -q` _has_ no results except for its exit status; that's the whole point of `-q`

Comment: @Fravadona, please don't use `$?` that way. `if result=$(grep ...); then ...` works just as well, and is less error-prone.

Comment: @Fravadona, ...for a longer discussion on the topic, see [Why is testing $? to see if a command succeeded or not an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Ah! forgot about it ^^ Thanks

Comment: @list'r, btw, the parens around the `grep` actually make your code slower. If you want to just create a command grouping without the side effect of spawning a subshell, that would be `if { grep -ERn 'break;|continue'; }; then ...`, but there's no reason to have any grouping at all here; `if grep -ERn 'break;||continue'; then` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
grep -ERn 'break;|continue' * && {
    echo "^-- Found breaks or continues."
    exit  # or return, if you put this code in a function.
}

echo "No breaks or continues found."
```

Comment: You should almost certainly `exit 1` if the `grep` matches anything.

Comment: Also, probably `grep ... >&2`

Comment: what is the reasoning behind each of these comments, @WilliamPursell?

Comment: @list'r error messages belong on stderr, and a program which fails should return non-zero.  A program whose purpose is check conformance with a style guide should succeed if the input matches the proscribed style, and fail if it does not.  Remarks about particular violations of the style should be considered error messages.